# Get properties from a .cs class file on disk

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vsix

I'm writing a VSIX extension for Visual Studio. With that plugin a user can select a class file from his solution explorer in VS, (so an actual `.cs` file somewhere on disk) and then perform a certain action on that file by triggering my VSIX code through a context menu item.

My VSIX extension needs to know what the `public` and `internal` properties are of the selected class file.

I'm trying to solve this by using a regex, But I'm kind of stuck with it. I can't figure out how to only get the property names of the class. It finds too much right now.

This is the regex I have so far:

```
\s*(?:(?:public|internal)\s+)?(?:static\s+)?(?:readonly\s+)?(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*[^(]
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ngM5l7/1
From this demo I want to extract all the property names, so:

```
Brand,
YearModel,
HasRented,
SomeDateTime,
Amount,
Name,
Address
```

PS. I know that a regex isn't the best for this kind of job. But I think I don't have any other options from a VSIX extension.

Comment: So what's the expected match in it ?

Comment: This sounds like a good use of the Microsoft Compiler Services (Roslyn). Why don't you think you have other options? I think it will be extremely difficult to get a reliable regex that would never capture false positives.

Comment: @Crowcoder As far as I know the Roslyn compiler needs "valid" code. So when I give it just any class file that has `using` statements to other classes, then it needs to load those as well. It cannot compile just one class file that lives in a big project.

Comment: So what is the problem with loading the whole project? This is exactly what the built in intellisense, etc, and things like ReSharper do. And, it can parse arbitrary blocks of code, what you can obtain from it may vary if there are unavailable references.

Comment: The regex101 site does not do .Net flavor regular expressions. I would not trust any *php* expressions to work in .Net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to only get the property names of the class.

This pattern is commented, so use `IgnorePatternWhiteSpace` as an option or remove all comments and join onto one line.

But this pattern gets all your data as you **provided in the example**.

```
(?>public|internal)     # find public or internal
\s+                     # space(s)
(?!class)               # Stop Match if class
((static|readonly)\s)?  # option static or readonly and space.
(?<Type>[^\s]+)         # Get the type next and put it into the "Type Group"
\s+                     # hard space(s)
(?<Name>[^\s]+)         # Name found.
```

1. Finds six matches (see below).
2. Extract the data from named match captures `(?<Named> ...)` such as `mymatch.Groups["Named"].Value` or by the hard integer.
3. In this case "Type" and "Name" are the group names or index or with hard ints.
4. Will find pattern in commented out sections.

My tool (created for myself) reports these matches and the groups :

```
Match #0
             [0]:  public string Brand
  ["Type"] → [1]:  string
  ["Name"] → [2]:  Brand

Match #1
             [0]:  internal string YearModel
  ["Type"] → [1]:  string
  ["Name"] → [2]:  YearModel

Match #2
             [0]:  public List<User> HasRented
  ["Type"] → [1]:  List<User>
  ["Name"] → [2]:  HasRented

Match #3
             [0]:  public DateTime? SomeDateTime
  ["Type"] → [1]:  DateTime?
  ["Name"] → [2]:  SomeDateTime

Match #4
             [0]:  public int Amount;
  ["Type"] → [1]:  int
  ["Name"] → [2]:  Amount;

Match #5
             [0]:  public static string Name
  ["Type"] → [1]:  string
  ["Name"] → [2]:  Name

Match #6
             [0]:  public readonly string Address
  ["Type"] → [1]:  string
  ["Name"] → [2]:  Address
```